# I am having trouble while Knitting RMarkdown file

Tags: r, knitr

I am getting following error while Knit my RMarkdown file.

```
Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 2, column 11
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted*
```

I understand it's my yaml header which is following -

```
---
title: "Data Wrangling Assessment"
author: ""ABC 11111""
subtitle: 
output: 
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  html_notebook: default
---
```

Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you wrapped the `author` name in doubled double quotes. If you want to quote the author name you have to

1. escape the inner double quotes using `\"`, e.g. `"\"ABC 11111\""`
2. replace the outer double quotes with single quotes, e.g. `'"ABC 11111"'`

```
---
title: "Data Wrangling Assessment"
author: "\"ABC 11111\""
subtitle: 
output: 
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  html_notebook: default
---
```

[image]